# Multiple ansible-playbook Execution with Error status

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am trying to execute multiple playbooks with master.yml file.
For each playbook PASS/FAIL summary I need to publish. Each playbook executes on multiple hosts, so can't use it in tasks. Any idea how to get the summary respect to each playbook I have included in master.yml ?

Comment: See `ansible-doc -t callback log_plays`

Comment: Hello Vladimir, Thanks for your response.

Comment: You're welcome. If you managed to get the summary you might want to post the answer. If not you can still update the question with the code you tried and ask for specific help. Make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/master/examples/example-250/test-1.yml).

Comment: I think still now I am not able to change the required configuration. What you have given in example is well enough for me. I am missing something may be whitelist the configuration. Currently I have executed the below command to whitelist it, If I need to do anything else, please let me know.           export ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=1